# Using Bayes formula

Tags: conditional-statements, artificial-intelligence, probability, bayesian, wumpus-world

suppose the cave system contains 100 caves, of which 90 caves are without a hidden treasure and 10 caves contain a buried gold object. In 70% of the caves with a hidden treasure, the Wumpus has left behind his usual stench from digging about and bumping into walls. In the remaining caves with hidden treasures in them, the Wumpus has left no trace, i.e. they are non-smelly. Furthermore, all the caves without a hidden treasure are free from smell, since the Wumpus has fled the cave system. The agent is now located in a random cave and can perceive that it is not smelly. What is the probability that this cave contains a hidden treasure?

how can I solve this using Bayes formula?
prob. of cave buried treasure = 10/100. 
prob. of cave Hidden treasure = 0.7
***HT- stands for Hidden treasure**

**p(HT/Cave) = (1/100*10/100)/(1/100*70/100*29/100*1/100)**

i have found the solution but i am not sure it is right or not ? can anyone help me?

Comment: What did you do from your side till now, add that to the quesiton

Comment: *HT- stands for Hidden treasure p(HT/Cave) = (1/100*10/100)/(1/100*70/100*29/100*1/100) i have did this

Comment: Prob. of cave without hidden treasure = 90/100.

Comment: prob. of cave buried treasure = 10/100. prob. of cave Hidden treasure = 0.7

Comment: Edit your question and add all this there.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know what's the probability of finding a hidden treasure if the cave is not smelly. So you want to calculate P(HT|notsmelly). Using Bayes' theorem that would be:

[image]

According to your data,

P(notsmelly|HT) = 0.3 and P(HT) = 0.1

P(notsmelly) is given by the 90 empty caves plus the 30% of the 10 treasured caves. So that would be 0.93.

So your probability should be (0.3 x 0.1)/0.93 = 0.0322 which is about 3%.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother for giving such nice explanation to solve my ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

Let  denote the event that the caves without a hidden treasure.

Let  denote the event that there is a treasure.

Now apply Bayes rule on (|)=()(|)/()=(()(|))/(()(|)+()(|)).

Comment: could you please explain about the Denominator of your mentioned formula? Now I am confused at this stage probability of caves without hidden treasure i.e. (|)) =?

Comment: for better understanding, you can refer to this below link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292768/probability-to-find-treasure